# Row Height in datatable

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, datatables

This is probably a silly question, but I have a jQuery datatable, and I am simply trying to determine the height of the inner data rows.  How can this be achieved?

I have tried:

```
$('#myTable tr').eq(0).height();
```

but it returns null.  I know that the rowHeight is automatic for this table; how do I find the height of a row in this particular table programatically?  I just need to fetch this value, not to change it.

Thanks.

**Edit:** HTML of table being displayed

```
<div class="dataTables_scroll">
  <div class="dataTables_scrollHead ui-state-default" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px; width: 100%;">
    <div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="width: 699px;">
      <table class="display dataTable" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 699px;">
        <thead>
          <tr role="row">
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 71px;"
            aria-label="Account #">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Account #</div>
            </th>
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 62px;" aria-label="CS_ID">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">CS_ID</div>
            </th>
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 69px;"
            aria-label="Service Code">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Service Code</div>
            </th>
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;"
            aria-label="Service Description">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Service Description</div>
            </th>
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 130px;"
            aria-label="STAT_EFF_DATE">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">STAT_EFF_DATE</div>
            </th>
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;"
            aria-label="Stat Description">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Stat Description</div>
            </th>
            <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 94px;"
            aria-label="Type Description">
              <div class="DataTables_sort_wrapper">Type Description</div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dataTables_scrollBody" style="overflow: auto; width: 100%; height: 37px;">
    <table id="vdmPtPropServiceListTbl" class="display dataTable" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 699px;">
      <thead>
        <tr role="row" style="height: 0px;">
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 71px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="Account #"></th>
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 62px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="CS_ID"></th>
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 69px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="Service Code"></th>
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 94px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="Service Description"></th>
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 130px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="STAT_EFF_DATE"></th>
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 94px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="Stat Description"></th>
          <th class="ui-state-default Center" tabindex="0" rowspan="1" colspan="1"
          style="width: 94px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; height: 0px;"
          aria-label="Type Description"></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
        <tr class="odd">
          <td valign="top" colspan="7" class="dataTables_empty">No data available in table</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show your HTML ?

Comment: Done - I notice there's a div height in there of 37px, if I could extract that somehow, that would be beneficial.

Comment: I see the workaround  , good .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a link to [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dekajp/7Zk98/5/)

```
 body {

      background:yellow;

  }
  .trclass {

      height:40px;

      font-weight:bold;

  }

<body>
    <button id="getw">Get table Height</button>
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <p>Sample paragraph to test height</p>
    <table id="myTable" border="1">
        <tr class="trclass">
            <td>row 1col 1</td>
            <td>row 1 col 2</td>
            <td>row 1 col 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:40px">
            <td>row 2 col 1</td>
            <td>row 2 col 2</td>
            <td>row 2 col 3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>



 function showHeight(ele, h) {
      $("div").text("The height for the " + ele +
          " is " + h + "px.");
  }

  $("#getw").click(function () {
      showHeight("table", $('#myTable tr').eq(0).height());
  });
```

Comment: If you look at my question, I tried $('#myTable tr').eq(0).height() and that came back as undefined.  Does it have something to do with the div wrapper?

Comment: Didn't work - eq(0).height() on my table is coming up as 0.  Even tried #myTable th to see - same thing.

Comment: can you make sure the CSS class is right ? height should work ,  whether you give height thru style tag or not.